# SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` in ... and where sum() less

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to make PHP `$where` as part of big query. I need something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM rf2aq_eb_events  
 WHERE id 
    IN ( SELECT event_id
              , SUM(number_registrants) summ 
           FROM rf2aq_eb_registrants 
          WHERE summ < event_capacity
       );
```

The `rf2aq_eb_events` table looks like:

```
ID | event_capacity

1  | 7  
2  | 5  
3  | 9
```

The `rf2aq_eb_registrants` table:

```
ID | events_id | number_registrants

1 | 1         | 6    
2 | 2         | 2   
3 | 3         | 4   
4 | 1         | 1    
5 | 2         | 0   
6 | 3         | 5
```

I need select events from the 'rf2aq_eb_events' for events with quantity of registrant < then event_capacity. There is event id = 2 respond the condition.

i've tried  `$where[] = 'a.id IN ( SELECT event_id FROM #__eb_registrants GROUP BY event_id HAVING sum(number_registrants) <  a.event_capacity)';`

It's working like SQL, but do not in php in the whole Query.

Below i've put php result.

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.location_id, 
       a.event_capacity, a.event_date, a.individual_price, 
       a.thumb, a.early_bird_discount_date, a.early_bird_discount_amount, 
       c.name AS location_name 
FROM #__eb_events AS a 
      LEFT JOIN #__eb_locations AS c 
      ON a.location_id = c.id 
WHERE a.published =1 
      AND DATE(event_date) between date(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
      and date(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 26 DAY) 
      AND (
         cut_off_date = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
         OR DATE(cut_off_date) between NOW() and date(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 26 DAY)
      ) AND a.id IN ( 
           SELECT event_id 
           FROM #__eb_registrants 
           GROUP BY event_id 
           HAVING sum(number_registrants) < a.event_capacity
      ) AND a.id IN (
           SELECT event_id FROM #__eb_event_categories 
           WHERE category_id IN (6,7)
      ) AND a.access IN (1,1) 
 ORDER BY a.event_date 
 LIMIT 4
```

Comment: The example query will never work, however it would be good to have the expected result in to the question.

Comment: I found mistake. Just removed a.event_capacity from select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the result of an aggregate (e.g. `SUM`) in a `WHERE` you can use it in a `HAVING` but you need to do a `GROUP BY` in this case as well:

```
SELECT * FROM `rf2aq_eb_events` e
WHERE `id` IN (
 SELECT `event_id` 
 FROM `rf2aq_eb_registrants` r 
 GROUP BY `event_id` 
 HAVING sum(`number_registrants`) <  `event_capacity`
)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but MySql send error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @VadimKozhevnikov Note that the select is only selecting `event_id` and not the sum.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use subqueries.

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `rf2aq_eb_events` as `e`
LEFT JOIN `rf2aq_eb_registrants` as `r`
ON `r`.`events_id`=`e`.`ID`
GROUP BY `r`.`events_id`
HAVING SUM(`r`.`number_registrants `) < `e`.`event_capacity`
```